# Using promise with closure in service with multiple $http.get

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-get, angular-promise

I've searched high and low but I just can't seem to wrap my head around q.defer() and creating my own promise.

I have a service `getDataService` which does exactly that - `$http.gets` data from a REST server.  However only one of each variable can be sent at a time, so if user wants to query server for two entities and return the entire associated data they must send two requests.  Because of this I had to use a method which kept `i` as the actual count (closure) which then runs my get data function the appropriate amount of times:

```
keepICorrect: function (security) {
        var self = this;
        for (var i = 0 ; i < entity.length; i++) {
            self.getDataFromREST(security, i);
        }
    },
```

I call this from my main controller as a promise :

```
$scope.apply = function (security) {

    var myDataPromise = getDataService.keepICorrect(security);
    myDataPromise.then(function () {

//DO STUFF

        }, 1);
    }, function (error) {
        alert("Error Retrieving Data");
        return $q.reject(error);
    });
}
```

This worked when using `.getDataFromREST()` but obviously doesn't now as I have to route through my new loop function, `keepICorrect()`.

My question is how on earth do I create a promise which spans from my service to my controller, but not only that, also waits to resolve or fail depending on whether the `i` amount of requests have completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an array of promises

```
keepICorrect: function (security) {
    var self = this;
    var promises = [];
    for (var i = 0 ; i < entity.length; i++) {
        promises.push(self.getDataFromREST(security, i));
    }
    return promises;
},
```

And then wait for all of them to complete using the `$q` library in Angular

```
$q.all(getDataService.keepICorrect(security))
.then(....
```

Comment: Wow, this seems to be working somewhat!  Problem now is somewhere along the way `security` (which is a user text input field) is now being passed to my `getDataFromREST()` function as `[object%20HTMLInputElement]`.  What is going on there?

Comment: Nevermind, got around it with `security.value`. Thank you so much for your help, I'm a step closer to understanding promises.